# How do I change my twitter widget to have a responsive height

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter, bootstrap-4

I am using react-twitter-widgets to embed a twitter timeline on my application. Currently, everything renders correctly, however, the timelines height stretches down the entire page. How do I get the widget height so that it only takes up the available view height? [image]

The underlying DOM structure for the main dashboard is:

```
<div className="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-2 px-3">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">
                        <TitleBar title={this.props.ticker} status={this.props.status}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-8">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-lg-12 mb-2">
                                <div className="card border-0">
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <Chart chart={this.props.predictionChart} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-lg-6">
                                <div className="card border-0">
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <Chart chart={this.props.errorChart}/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-lg-6">
                                <div className="card border-0">
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <Chart chart={this.props.volumeChart} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-lg-4">
                        <TwitterCard href={this.props.twitter} ticker={this.props.ticker}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

With the TwitterCard being in the following format:

```
import React from "react";
import { Timeline } from 'react-twitter-widgets';

export class TwitterCard extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.state = {
            ticker: props.ticker,
            href: props.href
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Timeline dataSource={{sourceType: 'URL', url: this.props.href}}/>
        )
    }
}
```

The main/only css file is as follows:

```
body {
    font-size: .875rem;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

/*
 * Title bar
 */
.title-bar {
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/*
 * Connection status
 */
#connection-status {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
}

#connection-status.connected {
    background-color: green;
}

#connection-status.disconnected {
    background-color: red;
}

/*
 * Sidebar
 */
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100; /* Behind the navbar */
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.sidebar-sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 48px; /* Height of navbar */
    height: calc(100vh - 48px);
    padding-top: .5rem;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidebar .nav-link {
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #333;
}

.sidebar .nav-link{
    margin-right: 4px;
    color: #999;
}

.sidebar .nav-link.active {
    color: #007bff;
}

.sidebar .nav-link:hover,
.sidebar .nav-link.active{
    color: inherit;
}

.sidebar-heading {
    font-size: .75rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*
 * Navbar
 */
.navbar-brand {
    padding-top: .75rem;
    padding-bottom: .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

.navbar .form-control {
    padding: .75rem 1rem;
    border-width: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.form-control-dark {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.form-control-dark:focus {
    border-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}

.full-screen{
    height: 100vh !important;
}

/*
 * Utilities
 */
.border-top { border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }
.border-bottom { border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please specify the JavaScript for rendering the widget. If it is same as below, you can adjust the height within the attribute.

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Timeline
    dataSource={{
      sourceType: 'profile',
      screenName: 'twitterdev'
    }}
    options={{
      username: 'TwitterDev',
      height: '400' 
    }}
    onLoad={() => console.log('Timeline is loaded!')}
  />
```

Comment: Won't that set a fixed height of 400? Instead of adjusting with the page?

Comment: Yes, it would. You have to use vh or % to set relative height.

Comment: When I use `100vh`, the widget is still slightly too large.

Comment: My preference is for it to be inline with the bottom of the graphs.

Comment: Inspect the outer element of the widget and set the height accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

How I solve this problem:

```
 HTMl:
     <Box className={classes.media}>
          <Timeline
            dataSource={{
              sourceType: "profile",
              screenName: "lbeegg",
            }}
            options={{ theme: "dark", width: "545" }}
          />
    </Box>

    CSS:
    media: {
    display: "flex",
    objectFit: "cover",
    width: "auto",
    height: "450px",
    overflowY: "scroll",
    borderRadius: "15px",
  },
```

I'm using material UI, so your code will be a little different. I put the  component inside a Div with a class named "media". In the css I used The **overflowY** with a **height in px** to solve the problem.