# Embedded Twitter tweet Height issue

Tags: css, twitter

I am trying to add the Twitter widget to my website but I am having a problem with the height of the widget.
This widget : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/embedded-tweets/overview

How to freeze the height of a tweet?

I would like to no longer have any degradation of the CLS on my site.

Is there a way to apply a ratio to the height? Or to know the size in advance?
The goal is to pre-book the location of the tweet.

Exemple :

```
<a class='twitter-tweet' data-id='123'>Tweet</a>

<script>
$.getScript('https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', function () {   
   if ($('.twitter-tweet').length > 0) {
      $('.twitter-tweet').each(function (t, tweet) {
         twttr.widgets.createTweet(
            $(this).attr('data-id'), tweet, {dnt: true }
         );
      });
   }                                             
}); 
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look on this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49402594/how-do-i-change-my-twitter-widget-to-have-a-responsive-height/73420234#73420234

In this case I used OverflowY.

Comment: A good new: https://vercel.com/blog/introducing-react-tweet

Answer (score 1):

If you pay attetion to the script you'll see a reference to class='twitter-tweet'. So every css related to this  will change how the content fits on screen. I suggest you to wrap this with a div and create a css class to manipulate the content. like:

```
 <div class="tweet-container">
   <a class='twitter-tweet' data-id='123'>Tweet</a>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .tweet-container {
     height: 200px; /* Set the desired fixed height here (e.g., 200px) */
     overflow: auto; /* Add a vertical scroll if the content overflows */
 }
```

You can use the inline-style too:

```
<div class="tweet-container" style={{ height: '200px', overflow: 'auto'}}>
 <a class='twitter-tweet' data-id='123'>Tweet</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but I lose the aspect ratio. And the frame look crap with the slider...
I found something similar to what I'd like:
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/layout-shift-terminator/
But how to make it universal for any iframe?